# adding a different id to the url each time a link is clicked

Tags: php, html, url, random

I have a link, and every time it is clicked i need to add a random id to the url, these id's can't be the same, and ideally need to be saved somewhere.

I'm working in php, which i'm pretty new to, therefore I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Do you have anything so far or are you hoping someone will write it for you? Do you need to save the Random ID to a database?

Comment: What is it for? you could just add <?=rand(1,1000000); ?> at the end of your link for an unlikely repetition, but it really depends on why you are doing it. -- edit. From reading your post below, don't use this then.

Comment: More context please. What is the problem in doing this? Appending a string to a URL? Generating the random ids? Saving them somewhere? What is the purpose of this anyway?

Comment: it's for an affiliate type thing, so the site it's linking to can see who's been referred, as we can cross reference the id's.. hope that makes sense

Comment: How are you going to tell from a *random* ID, where the client came from?

Comment: If you want unique IDs, [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) is your friend.

Comment: You'd need to connect to a database or something similar, not just generate a random number, or it is meaningless.

Comment: because the links only on my site?

Comment: @lucas you shouldn't give advices using short_tags to people that are new to php as on some installations that feature is off by default, and it could be annoying for him/her xD

Comment: You're right, it probably needed a little more explanation, my apologies.

Comment: If it's for an affiliate/referrer, why make the id *random*? Why not attach a value that's unique to the user, like the user id if you need to know which user was referred?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that

```
<a href="#" onClick="AppendIDToURL()">link</a>
```

and by using jquery

```
<script>
    var alreadyUsed = ""

    function AppendIDToURL(){
        var id ;
        var loop = true;
        while(loop){
            id = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            if (alreadyUsed.indexOf("," + id + ",") == -1){
                alreadyUsed += "," + id + ",";
                loop = false;
            }
        }
        var url = "temp.php/" + id;

        //use ajax or any other thing to save this id.
    }
</script>
```

Comment: A Javascript solution when a server-side solution will do? Not good.

Comment: The reason being, i don't know PHP, but i do know javascript that's why i posted the answer in javascript.